# Serialising/Deserialising multiple inherited Trivially Copiable C++ structs

Tags: c++

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct A {
  int a;
  A(int a): a(a) {}
  char *get_data() { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(this); }
};

struct B: public A {
  int b[100];
  B() : A(0) {}
};
```

Is it safe to do the following?

```
B b;
Write(/* key= */ 1, b.get_data());

A *a = reinterpret_cast<A *>(Read(1));
// Some code here.
B *b = reinterpret_cast<B *>(a->get_data());
```

Comment: no `reinterpret_cast ` is undefined behavior, and i'm pretty sure you are missing `()` on the first reinterpret_cast

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Also what if we move the array `b[100]` to A?

Comment: That kind of code is not portable. The main one being the size of an `int` and the endianness of the platform.

Comment: I am fine if it is not portable, if I want portability I would probably use protocol buffers. I want to know if my code will run in the same machine if that will always work.

Comment: `a.get_data()` won't compile for `A* a`

Comment: Compatibility could break due to changes in data-layout when you change compiler settings or upgrade your compiler to a new version.  (But if you only ever need to deserialize the data using the same executable build that serialized it, there’s no problem)